# how can I use gateway feather of fabric

Tags: python, fabric

My scenario:

```
Local host -> Gateway -> Remote host
```

I've already tried the gateway option:

```
fab -g user@host task
```

but it does not work. does anyone have instructions and tips?

this is the detailed infomation:

```
xdays@localhost:~/Public/fabric$ fab hello
[vps.xdays.info] Executing task 'hello'
[vps.xdays.info] run: echo Hello!
[vps.xdays.info] out: Hello!
[vps.xdays.info] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from vps.xdays.info... done.

xdays@localhost:~/Public/fabric$ vim fabfile.py

xdays@localhost:~/Public/fabric$ fab hello
[vps.xdays.info] Executing task 'hello'
[vps.xdays.info] run: echo Hello!
[vps.xdays.info] Login password for 'root': 
[vps.xdays.info] Login password for 'root': 
Stopped.
xdays@localhost:~/Public/fabric$ cat fabfile.py
from fabric.api import local, run, env

env.gateway = 'xdays@localhost'
env.user = 'root'
env.hosts = ['vps.xdays.info']
env.password = 'password'

def hello(name='world'):
    '''just hello'''
    run('echo Hello!')
```

Comment: any more information than "it does not work?" an error message? a timeout?